# How to develop modular application using Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

How to develop modular application using Zend framework?

Comment: Read the docs, make an effort then come back when you have written some code

Comment: there is nothing wrong in asking how to start, since he already said he is a newbie.

Comment: thanks alavi, infact i have tried a tutorial (http://phpdev.ro/zf-tutorial-series-part-1-module-based-app.html) in which the author just created his own directory structure which makes netbeans not to recognize it as zend project. actually i am using netbeans for dev and netbeans provide very nice facility to use netbeans commands from an interface within netbeans.

Comment: Here you'll find good resources http://alex-tech-adventures.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go through this tutorial [Modular application with Zend Framework](http://www.amazium.com/blog/create-modular-application-with-zend). There also some good tutorials on youtube, [zend framework-modular application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qblFgRAcCgk&translated=1)

Answer (score 2):

I made it working as a module based application, by just adding following lines in my application.ini

```
; FrontController Resource Settings
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

where i have "default" module as my default module and index controller/action as my default controller/action respectively.

Comment: Hi, i too followed the similar modular structure, and i am struck at implementing module specific models... can anyone point me in the right direction?